# SwiftUI: No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression' inside "if" statement

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I'm not sure if someone posted this before, I've searched about it and did not find a similar problem.

I've been struggling with this error "No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression'" after `LoginView()` (Line: 15) for a few days now. I'm a beginner in SwiftUI so I'm not sure why it appears suddenly, my app was working just fine.

Thank you so much!

Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State var search_shift = ""
@State var is_add_open = false
@State var alertMessage = false

@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel

var body: some View {
    Group {
        if (viewModel.userSession == nil) {
            LoginView() // Here is where I get the error
        } else {
            NavigationStack {
                VStack {
                    List {
                        Section(header: Text("On Duty")) {
                            //Retrieve Data
                            if(viewModel.employees.count == 0) {
                                Text("No Shifts found")
                            } else {
                                ForEach(viewModel.employees) { employee in
                                    //Employees Data
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } //End of List
                }
                .searchable(text: $search_shift)
                .navigationTitle("Shifts")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Button {
                            self.is_add_open.toggle()
                        } label: {
                            //Label("Add", systemImage: "plus")
                            Text("Add")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button {
                            //Signout
                            alertMessage = true
                        } label: {
                            Label("Signout", systemImage: "rectangle.portrait.and.arrow.forward")
                        }
                        .alert("Signout", isPresented: $alertMessage) {
                            Button("Yes", role: .destructive) {
                                viewModel.signOut()
                            }
                            Button("No", role: .cancel) {
                                //dismiss()
                            }
                        } message: {
                            Text("Are you sure you want to signout?")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $is_add_open) {
                    NewEmployeeView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type is `viewModel.employees`?

does employees confirm to the `Identifiable` protocol?

e.g.

```
struct Employee: Identifiable {
    let id: String
}
```

Either this or some other issue with the viewModel code will most likely fix your issue, I did not see any issues in the `ContentView` code.

Comment: Exactly there is no issue in 'ContentView', and yes it's a type of 'Employee' and it's Identifiable, when I added 'var id: String' it worked as you suggested! Thanks a lot!